# Updating State in a Single Cell (React)

Tags: reactjs, state

I have searched high and low and can't find an answer to my question. I've got a list of dates in React that I'm using to dynamically create a table. The date is the key. I also have a checkbox in a td, and if the person clicks the checkbox some info will be shown in the next td, but only for that date.

Unfortunately, any time a person clicks the checkbox, I can't figure out how to update state just in a particular cell. Instead, it updates the state for each row, not just the date clicked. Here's what I've tried: making show an object, holding both the id and "false." I've also tried getting rid of the conditional statement and using a document.write. I've googled the heck out of this, and can't seem to find anything that shows how to update state in a single cell, when the table is created dynamically.

```
import React from 'react';

class TablePage extends React.Component {
    state = { show: false, dates: ["8/21/19", "8/22/19", "8/23/19", "8/24/19"]   }

    handleClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let id = `${e.target.value}`
        let check = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("td")[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked === true
        if (check) {
            console.log(id);
            //I only want to update state in this cell below 
            let cellToTarget = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("td")[1]
            ////I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT HERE TO ONLY TARGET that cell??
            ///The code below updates the cell for each date, not just the one cliced
            this.setState(prevState => ({ show: !prevState.show }))
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table className="table"  >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Day</th>
                        <th scope="col">Clicked</th>
                        <th scope="col">Data</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.dates.map(i =>

                        <tr key={i} id={i} >
                            <th scope="row">{i}</th>
                            <td className={i}><input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value={i} onClick={(i) => this.handleClick(i)}></input> </td>

                            <td className={i}>{this.state.show ? "My row got checked!" : null}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}

export default TablePage
```

I know what is wrong in my code...I just don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are getting values in all the `td` because of this condition,

```
{this.state.show ? "My row got checked!" : null}
```

You must maintain an `array` of `checked checkboxes` to show the value in respective `td`.

```
state = {showMessage: []}
```

And your `handleClick` function should be,

```
handleClick = e => {
    let id = e.target.value;
    
    if(e.target.checked){
       //If check show message
       this.setState({showMessage:[...this.state.showMessage, id]})
    }else{
       //If uncheck the hide message
       this.setState({showMessage: this.state.showMessage.filter(date => date != id)})
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ajxsuj)

**Note:** Instead of `onClick` you must use `onChange` on `input`.

Comment: THANK YOU!!! Holy cow! I have been stressing about this for a while, and your answer makes perfect sense.  I truly appreciate the time you took to answer this, and I understand the flaws in my original code!!